# App Icon no longer working on iOS (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, appstore-approval, asset-catalog

I have been submitting updates of my app to the app store for over two years, but on my last submission, Apple suddenly rejected the submission.

> ITMS-90713: Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.gerrie.mobile.ios'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.

What's weird, is that my Info.plist file clearly has this value specified.

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

I have an asset catalog called "Media", and I have created an AppIcon asset. I have provided an image for each image size in the designer.

My Info.plist also contains a reference to this asset.

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Media.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

My csproj contains ImageAsset entries for each file in the catalog

```
<ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
<ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon1024.png">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
<ImageAsset Include="Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon120.png">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</ImageAsset>
... snip
```

Whenever I deploy my app to a device for debugging, the icon no longer shows up, and I just get the iOS default icon.

I am not sure what I am going wrong. Most help articles on this topic say that I need to use an asset catalog, but I am already using one.

Is there specific naming conventions that I need to follow, or something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue some time ago. So I modified my `info.plist` file as

```
  <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
        <string>Icon1024</string>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>Icon-60</string>
          <string>Icon-76</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

and it was enough for Apple to approve my app. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give this a try on Monday.